# Compiling same project gives different result after 2 months

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, margins, ubuntu

Ok, here's the deal. In December I finished writing a long document. I compiled it and went on vacations. I get back and after 2 I months compiled **the exact same project** with absolutely nothing changed and I get a different output. Trust me, I've changed **nothing**, not even the steps I use to compile.

This is what the different versions look like:

[image: WTF!]

The one on the left is the old version and the one on the right the new one. The only thing I can recall that changed in between both these files being created is that I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10, nothing more.

The files are being displayed in `Okular` by the way. You'll notice that now every hyperlink has its own rectangle around it. Now where in god's name this came from I have **absolutely no idea**.

The pages now begin a little lower in the page (ie: the top margin has somehow increased), which made the total number of pages go from 194 to 203.

What the hell is happening here?? Please help.

I can't upload all the files because the whole project is humongous but I can upload the file which contains the bulk of the packages and options being used: [here](http://pastebin.com/2ZgErHN9).

I'm getting this warning related to `hyperref` which I swear wasn't an issue before:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Invalid value `0'
(hyperref)                for option `pdfborder'.
(hyperref)                Option setting is ignored on input line 3941.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
```

PS: Also (for those of you who use Linux) the text inside the file is only searchable through Adobe Reader. `Okular` will only search text *inside* images (WTF!)

Comment: The correct format is `pdfborder=0 0 0` not `pdfborder=0`. Perhaps the ancient version of texlive in 12.04 did accept the latter as a bug/accident. Fixing this should remove the hyperlink boxes.

Comment: If you're using the TeX Live version that ships with Ubuntu, this isn't surprising. 12.04 comes with TL2009, 12.10 with TL2012. That is a pretty big difference.

Comment: This almost surely has to do with the default page settings (A4 or US Letter).

Comment: You change _absolutely nothing_ **but** the OS and most certainly the programs you use for producing this? `:-)`

Comment: @LevBishop: The correct format is `pdfborder={0 0 0}`. The braces are necessary to protect the spaces.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that worked for the hyperlinks. I had to manually change the margins to make it match. I thought LaTeX was a bit more stable than this, never imagined the end result could change by changing the system and not the project. Thank you all.